# If a roll is 6′ wide with a total area of 84 square yards, what is the length?

Tags: flooring

If a roll is 6′ wide with a total area of 84 square yards, what is the length?
The answer says 126 ft.
I keep getting 42
The explanation says:
"86 sq yd x 9 sq ft/sq yd = 756 sq ft"
756 sq ft ÷ 6 ft = 126 ft.
I still don't get the explanation. What the exact steps to solve the problem? Could the answer be wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem, not Home Improvement.

Comment: `I keep getting 42` .... 42 what?  ... carrots?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really a math problem and not DIY. But if this is referring to buying carpet or other roll products for a house then it could by DIY:

- Area = Width x Length *which is the same as* Length = Area / Width
- 1 yard = 3 feet

Total area = 84 square yards = 84 x (3 feet/yard) x (3 feet/yard) = 756 square feet

Width = (756 square feet) / (6 feet) = 126 feet

42 is the [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)) but it is not the correct answer to this math problem.

I suspect that somewhere you multiplied or divided by 3 (== feet per yard) instead of 9 (== **square** feet per **square** yard), as 126 / 3 = 42.

Comment: The 1/3 to get 42 is technicslly correct if the answer is in yards (1 yard / 3 feet), not feet. However, feet are the original specified dimension of width, so it makes sense to stay in units of feet for the length

Answer (score 0):

You're confused about *units*.

Area = length x width, but this presumes all units are the same unit.  You have:

> 84 **sq. yd.** = *length* x **6 feet**.

The purpose of this test question is to test your ability to do unit conversion when needed, *and to recognize when that is*. And you just faceplanted on that, because you [lost control of your units](http://www.cnn.com/TECH/space/9909/30/mars.metric.02/).

You know that numbers can cancel (factor) out if they are on opposite sides of an equal sign in an all multiply-divide expression, or on both top and bottom of a divide in an area that is all multiply-divide.  ***So can units***. In fact, units *have to*, or you get gobbledygook.

If the problem were this (noting that "square yard" is "yard x yard"):

> 84 **yard x yard** = *length* x **2 yards**

Then you could cancel out one appearance of *yards* on both sides, giving

> 84 yard = *length* x 2

See, *length* doesn't even have a unit when you start, but when you solve, it gets one!

---

But, unfortunately, your problem is not that.  However, in an all multiply-divide situation, you can always multiply either side by exactly 1 without having any effect on it.

> 84 **sq. yd.** = *length* x **6 feet** x 1.0

You can also multiply by a fraction that equals one, *and you can have **units** on both sides of that fraction*.  For instance 1 yard = 3 feet, so 1 yard / 3 feet = 1.  Try this.

> 84 yard x yard = *length* x 6 **feet** x *1 yard / 3 **feet***

Feet is on the top and bottom of a fraction, so it cancels out.

> 84 **yard** x yard = *length* x 6 x 1 **yard** / 3

Yards is on both sides of the equal sign, so one cancels out.

> 84 yard = *length* x **6 x 1 / 3**

You can take it from here.  And yes, 42 becomes correct with the right unit attached.